# Invalid Expression term '>' Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following Code :

```
return regex.Replace(sourceData, (MatchEvaluator)(oMatch => ReplaceItem(oMatch, oObject)));
```

i am using .Net 2.0 and i am getting an error `Invalid Expression term '>'`

how to solve this error ?

Comment: You might want to post what Regex you're using. As most likely the issue lies within

Comment: Are you also using VS2005, or a later version and just targetting .NET 2?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using a C# 3.0 (or later) compiler, then lambda expressions are not supported, and you'll have to use an [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) instead

```
return regex.Replace(sourceData, delegate(Match oMatch) { ReplaceItem(oMatch, oObject);});
```

(Not sure I've got it exactly right, I'm a little rusty)

Answer (score 0):

C# 2.0 doesn't have support for lambdas, you need to convert `oMatch => ReplaceItem(oMatch, oObject)` into [MatchEvaluator delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) type function.

Comment: lambdas are a language feature, not a .NET framework feature. You can use lambdas in .NET 2 compatible code, providing you're using a *compiler* that understands lambdas.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that is a correct remark. I've updated my answer.